# complex MySQL query with multiple tables (read for more details)

Tags: mysql, multiple-tables

I have 4 tables: Teams, Users, UserTeams and Permissions:

Users:

```
UserID | Name
------------------------
1      | John
2      | Mike
3      | Tom
```

Teams:

```
TeamID | Name
-------------------------------
1      | FC Barcelona
2      | Real Madrid
3      | Manchester United
4      | Liverpool
```

Permissions:

```
PermissionsID | Name
-------------------------------
1             | Read Comments
2             | Write Comments
3             | Send Email
4             | Admin
```

UserTeams:

```
ID | UserID | TeamID | PermissionID
--------------------------------------------
1  | 1      | 1      | 1
2  | 1      | 1      | 2
3  | 1      | 1      | 4
4  | 1      | 2      | 1
4  | 1      | 4      | 3
```

### -

### -

UserID = 1 (we know this before a query)

I want to make the query to get something like this:

```
Permission.Name | FC Barcelona | Real Madrid | Manchester United | Liverpool | etc...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Read Comments   | (something)  | (something) | NULL              | NULL
Write Comments  | (something)  | NULL        | NULL              | NULL
Send Email      | NULL         | NULL        | NULL              | (something)
Admin           | (something)  | NULL        | NULL              | NULL
```

Number of teams are not limited.

Any ideas? I dont't mind if there are multiple queries...

Thanks in advance!

***SOLUTION***

First select teams only:

```
SELECT TeamID, name FROM Teams
```

Then create a new query with Teams data:

```
SELECT     
Permissions.name as 'permissionName', 

<Loop this line with the previous query>
    MAX(CASE WHEN Teams.name = 'FC Barcelona' THEN Teams.name ELSE NULL END) AS 'FC Barcelona'
<End loop>

FROM Permissions
LEFT JOIN UserTeams ON UserTeams.PermissionID = Permissions.PermissionID AND UserTeams.UserID = '1' 
LEFT JOIN Teams ON Teams.TeamID = UserTeams.TeamID   
GROUP BY Permissions.name
```

Now we have exactly the result we wanted.

Comment: Read up on Pivot Tables: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table

Comment: Problem with Pivot tables is to make those dynamic...

Answer (score 1):

Well i think your tables are incomplete.. where will be that '(something)' will be stored

Comment: if there are permissions for the row/column the (something)value can be anything.
if there are no permissions then the row/column is NULL

Answer (score 0):

The number of columns in a query result is not variable, you will always get the same number of columns. So I would recommend a query result like this:

```
Permission     | Team                |  User_name |  User_id
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Read Comments  | FC Barcelona        | John       | 1
Write Comments | Real Madrid         | John       | 1
Send Email     | Manchester United   | Mike       | 2
Admin          | ...(unlimited)      | Tom        | 2
```

(of course with correct values ;) )

The SQL query for this would be:

```
SELECT 
    p.Name AS Permission,
    u.Name AS User_name,
    t.Name AS Team,
    u.id AS User_id
FROM
    UserTeams AS ut
INNER JOIN
    Users AS u ON (ut.UserId = u.UserId)
INNER JOIN
    Teams AS t ON (ut.TeamId = t.TeamId)
INNER JOIN
    Permissions AS p ON (ut.PermissionId = p.PermissionsId)
WHERE
    u.UserID = :userId
```

Comment: Hmm... how this would help if I need to get list of permissions for every team for selected user (UserID = 1)?

Comment: `permissions = array()`  
`foreach($result as $row){`  
`  $permissions[$row['User_id']][$row['Team']][$row['Permission']]=$row['Persmission'];  
`}`    now you have an array and you can iterate with foreach... It's the best solution because you just need one query